# tflint isn't creating the right xml file when using the command option "--format junit"

Tags: azure, junit, terraform, devops

tflint isn't creating the right xml file when using the command option "--format junit".

I am using this command: tflint --format junit > TEST-tflint.xml.
I am getting an error in the terminal, but the XML file is not showing any errors!

The xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite tests="0" failures="0" time="0" name="">
      <properties></properties>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

The error :

```
Failed to load configurations; 00_rg.tf:1,40-2,1: Invalid block definition; A block definition must have block content delimited by "{" and "}", starting on the same line as the block header.:

Error: Invalid block definition

  on 00_rg.tf line 1:
   1: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg"
   2:   name     = "rg${local.suffix}"

A block definition must have block content delimited by "{" and "}", starting on the same line as the block header.
```

can anyone help ? or explain why this is happening ?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.